Why does C# compiler gives CS0704 error when trying to use an abstract static interface on a template?
I am trying to implement a C# static abstract interface. I have read the docs and the blogs, and I can't see what I am doing wrong.
  public interface IModel
  {
    abstract static PropertyInfo KeyProperty { get; }
    abstract static string TableName { get; }
  }

  public abstract record Model<TKey>: IModel
  {
    public static PropertyInfo KeyProperty { get; }
    public static string TableName { get; }
    ...
  }

  public Repository<TModel, TKey> where TModel : Model<TKey>
  {
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
      // This throws a compiler error: "CS0704 Cannot do non-virtual member lookup in 'TModel' because it is a type parameter"
      var col = TModel.KeyProperty.Name;
    }
  }


For some reason, the compiler is unable to ascertain that TModel implements IModel, even though it inherits from a class that implements IModel. The solution, fortunately, is simple. Instead of this:
  public Repository<TModel, TKey> where TModel : Model<TKey>

do this:
  public Repository<TModel, TKey> where TModel : Model<TKey>, IModel

